# azure storage blob getting deleted suddenly

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Storage BLOB in my project to store images and those images used to display in my webpage. The problem is in every 2-3 days I can see one or two images not displaying in my webpage. Its getting 404 for those images. Using Storage explorer also those blobs are not available in the container. I have also updated the retention days for Storage account to 0 , still its happening. I could not reproduce this issue its happening just suddenly.
It would be great if you can give some idea on this.
My Delete Blob code

```
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(systemImageName);
        return blob.DeleteIfExists();
```

Comment: You can enable diagnostics on your storage account with delete logging. That might give you a clue.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your answer to show some code, especially where you add (and delete) items from blob storage. Also, what do you mean by "*update the retention days for Storage account to 0*"?

Comment: Yes Ben.. I have done that , I can also see that that specific BLOB is deleted. But I cannot find the reason for that.

Comment: David: In the azure storage account , under configure tab there is a option to set the retention days for a blob i.e after that days blob will be deleted automatically. "0" means retention policy is not applied.

Comment: @SantanuDutta - those are monitoring and logging retention policies. They have nothing to do with blob content; you store something in a blob, and it stays in a blob until you delete it. That's why I suggested editing your question to show possible deletion paths in your code.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for the explanation , My understanding was wrong. I have updated the query

Comment: Ok you updated with your deletion code, but you don't show how/when it's called. And that's likely to be the source of your issue (since blobs can't just go away without being explicitly deleted).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am calling those blobs just as a URL. Those are images and displayed in the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the retention policy you are referring to is for storage log files - not stored data. This troubleshooting guide shows you possible causes of 404's
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#the-client-is-receiving-404-messages including how to diagnose.